# Change Laravel route parameter

Tags: php, laravel-5

In the platform I'm developing it's possible to request the user's company data by sending a GET request to the `api/company/{id}` API endpoint.

By default the `id` parameter is an integer but usually it's also possible to set it as a string: `api/company/mine` will retrieve the authenticated user's company data.

In order to allow this I created a middleware that intercepts the API call and replaces `mine` with the actual company ID.
Unfortunately, my solution is  not exactly what I had in mind.

Here's my current solution:

```
$request->merge([
    'id' => $request->user()->company
]);
```

This works by adding the id to the request's input so that it can be accessed later on using `$request->input('id');`, but the problem is that if I try to access `$request->route('id')` I still get the old value.

Is it possible to change the route parameter directly?

*P.S.*

Another solution that comes in my mind is to actually programmatically create a new request with the new parameter and then pass that one to the `next()` function in the middleware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that the best solution in this case, at least for me, was to deal with it in the request passed as a parameter in the controller action and in the model repositories.

The problem with creating a new request is that it's just partially working since the route parameters are not updated and it's not possible to update the route parameters manually without a lot of additional code.

Another possible solution is to redirect the request to the right API endpoint or deal with it in the controller.

Answer (score 10):

Hit a similar issue, and with some digging through the laracasts forums, someone has noted down an alternative that I have successfully used:

```
$request->route()->setParameter('id',  $request->user()->company);
```

Reference (last post):
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/change-laravel-route-parameter